# I am trying to scale each image to be the same size with css (using react) but there is distortion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, frontend

so I am trying to set the images I have to be the same size in a responsive gallery, eventually they will be clickable, currently when I set the height and width to be the same, the images get distorted if they have to stretch, but this should not be an issue as the image they are trying to fit under is much smaller than the origin.

Thanks for your time.

my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cerf-6bbo8

my component

```
const ImageView = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <ul className="flex-container wrap">
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <li className="flex-item" key={index}>
          {/* <Link to={`/api/posts/item/${item._id}`}> */}
          <img
            className="single-image"
            src={item.image[0]}
            alt="shows what this post is offering"
          />
          {/* </Link> */}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default ImageView;
```

css :

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.nowrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap li {
  background: transparent;
}

.wrap-reverse {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
.wrap-reverse li {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;

  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.single-image {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Why not wrap each image in a `div` tag and then scale the images with max-height/width and position them in the middle of the `div`?

Comment: no, I want images to be the same size

Comment: Due to some images having different dimensions and you forcing a different height/width it will reshape the image if the scale difference isn't the same from height to width... hence the distortion. Think of a landscape image being force to match the dimensions of a portrait image...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make the images of same widht and height if they are not.
The best that could be done is set height and width to the parent element of the image and let the images adjust accordingly.
See below the sample code:

```
.wrap li{
     width:300px;
     height:300px;
 }
.single-image {
    width: 100%;
}
```